# blackberry webworks: trackpad scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

i have several focusable elements in my app, so when i'm focusing a scrollable div, the focus goes to another focusable element instead of scrolling that div when using the trackpad. how can i prevent this? i want it to scroll that div first, and if it cant scroll anymore then jump to the next element. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Kitchen Sink example for scrolling Divs:
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/css3/overflow.html

NOTE: Use Firebug/Chrome Developer tool to view the javascript doing all the work.